# Colorbox popup opens additional parent window

Tags: javascript

I have a popup window that uses colorbox, inside of the popup I have a link that open a second popup:

```
<a target="<?php print $target; ?>" class="colorbox-load" 
ref="<?php print url(REPLACE_PATH_REPIN.'/'.$node->nid); ?>?width=800&height=880">
```

The problem is: when I click on this link it seems that I have open additional parent window, anybody knows why?

Thanks!!